# how to run the blade compiler explicitly?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, assets

for example there is a blade file at "⁨resources⁩/views/home.blade" so we want to compile the file into plain php file at location "root/⁩public", is there any artisan command or anything to do the task?

Comment: you would probably have to call the compiler yourself and do this in code

Comment: you can view your php compile in laravel storage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [BladeCompiler](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/8.x/src/Illuminate/View/Compilers/BladeCompiler.php) directly:

```php
<?php

/** @var \Illuminate\View\Compilers\BladeCompiler */
$compiler = app('blade.compiler');
$srcPath = resource_path('views/home.blade.php');
$targetPath = public_path('home.php');

$compiled = $compiler->compileString(file_get_contents($srcPath));
file_put_contents($targetPath, $compiled);
```